# How to install Skype on Debian 8?

Tags: debian, software-installation, skype

Can you install a program made for Debian 7 on Debian 8?

Specifically I need Skype, but it only has support for Debian 7; could I install that? I know it's preferable to use Linux- and community-supported programs, but need it to communicate with people that don't use Linux based programs.

Comment: This worked for me yesterday, comprehensive instructions  https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2015/09/06/installing-skype-on-debian-8-0-jessie/ essentially use `dpkg` to add i386 architecture support, which takes a while to download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no general answer; in many cases programs made for Debian 7 will work for Debian 8, although you'll often need to install supporting packages from Debian 7.

In Skype's case, you should install the [Skype alpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) anyway if the people you want to communicate with are using Skype on Windows or macOS, since the old Linux client can no longer communicate with current versions of Skype on these platforms. The Skype alpha is available for Debian 8; simply download the `.deb` and install it using [`gdebi`](https://tracker.debian.org/gdebi):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64-alpha.deb
```

You'll find detailed instructions regarding all versions of Skype on Debian 7, 8 and 9 on the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/skype).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the alpha, but following these excellent instructions https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2015/09/06/installing-skype-on-debian-8-0-jessie/ I didn't notice any compatibility problems.

Comment: Verified. Works!

Answer (score 0):

To open Skype you should to do following:

```
$ sudo apt install snapd
$ sudo snap install skype --classic
# wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some explanation of what the commands do, e.g., a brief explanation of `snap`.

Comment: i will definitely  keep in find next time whenever i will put something