# Skype on Debian 8 (Jessie) runs but no window is showing

Tags: linux, debian, skype

I have "succesfully" installed skypeforlinux 8.57.0.116 on my machine running Debian 8 (Jessie) using the instructions provided [here](https://wiki.debian.org/skype). An icon appears in the menu, and when I click that icon six skypeforlinux processes start, but no window is showing. The icon appears on the taskbar for a while, but then disappears. If I try to start Skype from the terminal by giving the command `skypeforlinux`, again six skypeforlinux processes start, but again no window is showing. Any ideas about what might be the trouble here?

I am aware that there have been previous questions asked on this site about installing Skype on Debian Jessie (e.g. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333126/how-to-install-skype-on-debian-8)), but they do not address the issue that I have with my installation.